The path <path> in the environment variable AMENT_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS 2 distro: Humble
Whenever I delete a package from the src directory of my workspace and then delete the directories build, install and log for a clean new build, I get the following warnings:
WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.ament:The path '<path_to_ws>/install/<deleted_pkg>' in the environment variable AMENT_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path '<path_to_ws>/install/<deleted_pkg>' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist

I know that the directory doesn't exist, that's exactly what I want.
How can I "clean up" the AMENT_PREFIX_PATH and CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variables to get rid of these warnings?
I tried to manually change the environment variables before building. But they are reset in a new terminal, so the problem repeats on the next build.

To actually do a clean build, you need to make sure to un-source the workspace that you are about to build, before running the build command.
That might involve:

delete build install log folders
delete the line that sources your workspace from the .bashrc,
open a new shell,
source the desired underlay workspace(s), e.g., the global installation,
run colcon build for your workspace for an actually clean build.

In fact, it is generally recommended to not have the workspace sourced, while building it. Apparantly it might cause other (subtle) problems, too.
Related: ROS2 recommended handling of workspace setup.bash

You can try the following:
unset AMENT_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH && unset CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH && sudo reboot

You first unset an environment variable.  And then reboot your system.  What's also a hard way to unset the environment.
